# DataURI client side create, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So the need arises that I present the end user with an image, and the ability to draw a selection in this image, convert the cropped selection to a DataURI (base64 encoded) and pass it to a webservice.

Are there any jquery libs that can help with this:

1. allow crop style selection of an image on a page
2. parse selected crop client side into a new image DataUri encoded

I think I may be cruising for punishment?

I could pass the whole image up to the server each time with co-ordinates but using Azure the bandwidth is expensive, that.. is my problem :)

thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

There are client-side libraries for image manipulation (eg. [CamanJS](http://camanjs.com/)), or you can do it manually using HTML5 canvas. Canvas data can be easily exported as DataURI by `canvas.toDataURL()` method.